# Trim url of slash and period

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I am trying to validate a URL when i am sending it through a form, I want to make sure it begins with either https or http, has at least one period, and then doesn't have a period or trailing slash at the end. I have achieved the http and period bit through the use of regex, however I can't seem to work out how to trim the url if it has either . , ./ , /.  or / I use rtrim but it only works if it finds the single characters, is there a way to remove both of them if appear?

Here is my code:

```
//update the canonical url
        $canonical_url = $_POST ['canonical_url'];
        $valid_url =  preg_match('/^(http[s]?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/', $canonical_url );
        if ($valid_url) {
            $removed_period = rtrim($canonical_url, '.');
            $final_canonical = rtrim($removed_period, '/');
        }
```

Comment: you can user str_replace to replace . and / with '' @pocockn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) to validate your URL and `preg_replace` to trim the trailing `.`, `./`, `/.` or `/`, if any.

```
$canonical_url = $_POST['canonical_url'];
if (filter_var($canonical_url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED)) {
    $final_canonical = preg_replace('/(\.|\.\/|\/\.|\/)$/', '', $canonical_url);
}
```

> Note that `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` allows any RFC 2396 compliant URI, so if you only admit http/https, you could add:

```
if(filter_var(…) && strpos($canonical_url, 'http') !== false) {…}
```